# Using a splash screen across activities

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've a login screen as my first activities. It has an `AsyncTask` object for login verification using web services. It loads the main activity which has tabs as activities. The main activity then loads my first tab which also has an `AsyncTask` object to load some data. I want to show a splash screen from the start of login verification (`onPreExecute` of LoginActivity) till the FirstActivity loads its data (`onPostExecute` of FirstActivity). I've started implementing it but I was denied the desired result. The splash screen goes away after the `onPostExecute` of LoginActivity and the login screen reappears for a split second. After that my FirstActivity loads without a showing splash screen.

How do I continue showing the splash screen across these activities?

I'm aware that this sounds quite complex. But I've spent a lot of time to figure this out on my own and I haven't succeeded yet. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**

LoginActivity:

```
    public Dialog mSplashDialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

            et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Login_ID);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Passward);

    // Activity Specicfic code

    }
protected void showSplashScreen() {
    mSplashDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.SplashScreen);
    mSplashDialog.setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    mSplashDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mSplashDialog.show();
    }
public class LoginProcess extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    private LoginActivity activity;


    private LoginProcess(LoginActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    /**
     * Showing the dialog on the UI thread.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showSplashScreen();
    }

    /**
     * Performing the heavy lifting in the background thread thread.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {


        // User Validation  


    }

    /**
     * When the task is completed, notifiy the Activity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("FromOtherTab", true);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }


}
```

MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // create tabs and set current tab to FirstActivity

    }
```

FirstActivity:

```
public Dialog mSplashDialog;
private FetchData mTask;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mydashboard);

  }

protected void removeSplashScreen() {
    if (mSplashDialog != null) {
        mSplashDialog.dismiss();
        mSplashDialog = null;
    }

private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

private FirstActivity activity;


/**
 * Performing the heavy lifting in the background thread thread.
 */
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
    // Load data

}

/**
 * When the task is completed, notifiy the Activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    // Here I want to call removeSplashScreen();

}
```

Currently, the splash screen loads until the LoginActivity thread is running. After that, FirstActivity starts. A blank layout appears for a second (until the data from FirstActivity is loaded) and then the proper screen is displayed. I want to continually show the splash screen until the onPostExecute of FirstActivity. If I create a new mSplashDialog in FirstActivity then I get two separe instances of splashscreen. First disappears just before the new one appears. I'm not sure how to get the same mSplashDialog spinning when FirstActivity loads.

Comment: Assuming LoginActivity and FirstActivity live on tabs of MainActivity, you could have the Splash View as a child view of your MainActivity (i.e. the one with the tabs).  It would be configured as Visibility=INVISIBLE or GONE.  To display the Splash, you set its Visibility property to VISIBLE, then set it to INVISIBLE to make it disappear.

Comment: Oh no! LoginActivity is a separate activity which launches MainActivity

Comment: If you add your code, we can offer better help. At this point we are simply speculating at what might be.

Comment: where is your IncludeTabActivity?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you are calling your edit text in your background thread. This should be on your main thread.

Comment: IncludeTabActivity is the MainActivity. I should've renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, what I would do is create a splash screen, without the `AsyncTask`. From there, I would create an `AsyncTask` that will load while the splash screen is being displayed. In the `onPostExecute`, I would then move from the splash screen to your next activity. Basically, if you put all the background activities in the `AsyncTask` and have the splash screen run on the main UI thread, you should be okay. Within the splash screen activity, you would just launch the `AsyncTask`, and the `onPostExecute` would move you from the splash activity, to the main activity.

I hope that makes sense. Here is a great link that will help with `AsyncTask`:

www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1823692&seqNum=3

Best of luck!

Comment: That is a lot of rework! I have two asyntasks specific to the activities. To move them to a single processing thread would involve many changes. As the loaded data in each activity goes into the UI fields of the layout of that particular activity I will have to send many values across activities as well. That would be my last resort.

Comment: Well, without seeing your code it is hard to give an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the splashscreen from onPreExecute of your asynctask, then close it onPostExecute (as you are currently doing)